# Programmatically Position excel ListBox

Tags: excel, listbox, programmatically-created

I need to dynamically create and delete 1 - N number of listboxes on a worksheet.  Because the page will be changing I can't know in advance where to place the control so a statement like ... Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=106.8, Height:=154.6 won't work.  I need to be able to programmatically place controls at C1 or C55 for example.

The research I've done found only examples of static creation at a fixed location and I also haven't been able to find anything that will give me the coordinates of a cell (ex: C1 = Left:=65, Top:87).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
Dim i&, n&, r As Range

n = 3
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To n
        Set r = .Range("c1")(i)
        .ListBoxes.Add r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height
    Next
End With
```

This simply demonstrates how to use the dimensions and coordinates of a cell as the dimensions and coordinates of the control. It will be off a bit on height. You can adjust that.

Additionally you can use whatever mechanism you wish to identify the cells. I just did the three top cells of column C.

Comment: Good answer.  Adds a `FormControl` listbox.  Alternatively to add a `ActiveX` listbox use `.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1",  ...`